# Refactor nested 'foreach' and 'If' to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm learning some LINQ. When having something like this:

```
foreach (var user in result.Items)
{
    if (!(user.UserId.Equals(session.UserId)))
    {
        user.CanBeDeleted = true;
    }
}
```

How it can be resolved with LINQ? Is it better performing LINQ or the foreach-if combination?

Comment: LIN(Q) is used to query something, use a loop to modify it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Well regardless of `LinQ` that still could be written as `user.CanBeDeleted = (!user.UserId.Equals(session.UserId) || user.CanBeDeleted) ` without the `If`

Comment: I don't see any nested foreach here.

Comment: Linq is generally expected to be free of side effects.  Given that you're mutating the state of a collection you're iterating over, this is not the use case for it.

Comment: @chancea: no, your solution would set user.CanBeDeleted to false if the user id was not equal. His code doesn't change CanBeDeleted in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases LINQ does not make  your program run  faster but it makes your code more readable and therefore easier to maintain.

But if you need to modify something LINQ is not the right tool. The `Q` stands for query. Use a plain loop to modify it. But you can filter what you have to modify:

```
var toBeDeleted =  result.Items.Where(u => u.UserId != session.UserId);
```

Now you can use a loop to execute it and change the `User`:

```
foreach(User user in toBeDeleted)
    user.CanBeDeleted = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result.Items.Where(user => 
    !user.UserId.Equals(session.UserId)).ToList()
    .ForEach(user => user.CanBeDeleted = true);
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to convert to a list just so you can use `ForEach`.

Comment: `ForEach` method isn't any better than `foreach` loop.

Comment: Hey, I'm not the one asking for a Linq version. And usually it comes with "one-liner".